# Reading images from file in C++

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

I have bmp images in image folder on my computer.I named it from 1.bmp to 100.bmp .

I want to read  one by one  these hundered images.And I wrote this code:

```
int i;
System::String^s;

for(i=1;i<=100;i++)
{
s=("C:\\images\\%d.bmp",i);
System::Drawing::Bitmap^ image;
image= gcnew System::Drawing::Bitmap(s,true );
}
```

And VS 2008 gave error in `s=("C:\\images\\%d.bmp",i);`

```
error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'System::String ^'
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: Is this native C++ code? Managed or unmanaged?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
s=String::Format("C:\\images\\{0}.bmp",i);
```

Comment: I do not think so, String.Format can not recognize %d, as %d used in standard c/c++ functions (i.e. printf,sprintf..etc)

Answer (score 2):

I do not know much more about C++/CLI but in C# you can use

```
s = String.Format("C:\\images\\{0}.bmp",i);
```

I think in c++/cli may be

```
s = String::Format("C:\\images\\{0}.bmp",i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s=("C:\\images\\%d.bmp",i);
```

This statement is wrong. I am not expert in C# but I think you can do following

```
s= "C:\\images\\" + i + ".bmp";
```